# Retain drop-down menu choices each time the table is reset

Tags: r, shiny, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with the R Shiny server part of my code. I want to keep the choices made in the menus between each reset of the table, for each polygon. I've managed to do this for the text boxes in the "References" column, and I want to do the same for the drop down menus in the "Status" column.

```
init_input <- function(inputId, value, index) {
      tags$script(
        paste0("$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#", inputId, "').val('", value, "');
            Shiny.setInputValue('", inputId, "', '", value, "', {priority: 'event'});
        });")
      )
    }
    
######################################
values_references <- reactiveVal(list())

observe({
  values_list <- lapply(seq_along(zmm$References), function(index) {
    inputId <- paste0("text_area_", zmm$CD_SIG[index])
    input[[inputId]]
  })
  values_references(setNames(values_list, zmm$CD_SIG))
})
#####################################

# renderDT
output$table2 <- renderDT({
  selected_polygons <- selected_polygons_data()
  selected_data <- zmm[zmm$CD_SIG %in% selected_polygons$id, ]
  selected_data <- selected_data[match(selected_polygons$id, selected_data$CD_SIG), ]
  
  # new table
  new_table <- data.frame(
    polygone_name = selected_data$LB_ADM,
    Statuts = mapply(function(statut, index) {
      inputId <- paste0("drop_down_menu_", index)
      
      # drop-down menu
      select_input <- tags$select(
        init_input(inputId, "select", index),  
        tagList(
          tags$option(value = "No information", "No information", selected = (statut == 1)),
          tags$option(value = "Probable or certain absence", "Probable or certain absence", selected = (statut == 2)),
          tags$option(value = "Confirmed disappearance", "Confirmed disappearance", selected = (statut == 3)),
          tags$option(value = "Probable presence", "Probable presence", selected = (statut == 4)),
          tags$option(value = "Certain presence", "Certain presence", selected = (statut == 5)),
          tags$option(value = "select", "select", selected = is.null(statut), disabled = "disabled")
        ),
        onchange = paste0("Shiny.setInputValue('", inputId, "', this.value, {'priority': 'event'})"),
        style = "color: black;"
      )
      as.character(select_input)
    }, selected_data$Statuts, seq_along(selected_data$Statuts)),
    References = mapply(function(polygone_id, references, index) {
      inputId <- paste0("text_area_", polygone_id)
      
      text_input <- tags$input(
        type = "text",
        value = values_references()[as.character(polygone_id)],  
        onchange = paste0("Shiny.setInputValue('text_area_", polygone_id, "', this.value, {'priority': 'event'})")
      )
      as.character(text_input)
    }, selected_data$CD_SIG, selected_data$References, seq_along(selected_data$References)),
    
    polygone_CD_SIG = selected_data$CD_SIG
  )
  
  global_new_table(new_table)
  
  # DataTable
  datatable(
    new_table,
    escape = FALSE,
    editable = list(
      target = 'cell',
      disable = list(columns = c(1, 4)),
      options = list(
        target = 'cell',
        disable = list(columns = c(1, 4)),
        options = list(
          "Statuts" = list(type = "select"),
          "References" = list(type = "text")
        )
      )
    )
  )
})
```

I tried to use this code, but it didn't work

```
selected_statuts <- reactiveVal(list())

observe({
  values_statuts <- lapply(seq_along(zmm$Statuts), function(index) {
    inputId <- paste0("drop_down_menu_", zmm$CD_SIG[index])
    input[[inputId]]
  })

  selected_statuts(setNames(values_statuts, zmm$CD_SIG))
})
```